# Any other way to write a loop for multiplication table to take run time values?

Tags: c++, c

To print multiplication tables, I'm using a for loop which has fixed values up to 10th times table only. I need multiplication table as run time values. Is there an alternate loop to take the values at run time? Here is the code which i tried:

```
scanf(&num); 
for(i=num;i<=num;i++) 
    for (j=1;j<=10;j++)
```

Comment: What does this have to do with python?

Comment: For the outer loop you already read `num` at runtime. You can simply do the same for the inner loop

Comment: For example add `scanf(&inner);` and `for (j=1;j<=10;j++)` -> `for (j = 1; j<= inner; j++)`?

Comment: the loop which you said giving the output error

Comment: sir uring inner as run time value it giving wrong output sir

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is not a Python For loop

In python,you can use the **Range** function to have a nice multiplication table.

```
def table_choice(my_choice=None):
    for a in range(10):
        if my_choice != None:
            print('{0} x {1} = {2}'.format(my_choice, a, my_choice * a))
        else:
            for b in range(10):
                print('{0} x {1} = {2}'.format(a, b, a * b))

table_choice(my_choice = 7)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
7 x 0 = 0
7 x 1 = 7
7 x 2 = 14
7 x 3 = 21
7 x 4 = 28
7 x 5 = 35
7 x 6 = 42
7 x 7 = 49
7 x 8 = 56
7 x 9 = 63
```

In case you execute **table_choice()** you will get the full table

See the Range documentation in : https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range

Comment: Huh? Why has this answer been accepted? It's not an answer to the question?

Comment: yes but i trying this using python also thats why i accepted your answer sir. can u help me out i need run time values not fixed values. if i press 7 then i should get only 7 table not all the tables. please tell the solution sir....

Comment: See my edit , this is answering your comment :)

Comment: ok sir i will try this and i will let you know for further quries